# try to install SQL2008 on windows 7 but got some error

Tags: windows, sql-server-2008, 64-bit, x86

I try to install SQL2008 enterprise ON WINDOWS 7 64bit & 32bit but I got the same error when I installed it I chose instance feature only and the error which I got "on Wait on the Database Engine recovery handle failed. Check the SQL Server error log for potential causes."

How can I solve this problem please try to discuss step by step because I read some solutions but didn't work

Comment: what is "instance feature only"?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, SQL2008 (and R2) **Enterprise** won't install on a Workstation OS - only Server.

[SQL 2008 R2 Enterprise OS requirements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143506.aspx#EE32)

[SQL 2008 Enterprise OS requirements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143506(v=SQL.100).aspx#EEx64)

Comment: The only editions of SQL Server that will run on client OSs are Developer (which is only licensed for development and test) and Express.